Creating function in package is changing data table syntax from := to `:=`
I have written a function - just running the text of it works fine, setting it up as a function works fine, but when I create a package to load the function it changes some of the syntax and then crashes.
Due to the complexity of the issue, I am not certain a reproducible example is possible....
One example of the code is it changing this:
y1[fueltype=="Petrol",fueltype:="PETROL"]

to this:
y1[fueltype == "Petrol", `:=`(fueltype, "PETROL")]

and although this should be OK as far as I can tell (and indeed if I just run the code from the function that has been changed it runs OK), when I run the function it returns the error:
"Error: Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, :=, :=(...) and let(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").:
Is there any reason why:
a) it insists on changing the code when I create the function via a package
b) it refuses to run the edited code, even when it appears to have changed it to something that should be acceptable.
Again - apologies for the lack of reproducible code but as the process involves setting up new packages it didn't seem that this was practicable.

This is an answer to part a) of your question, and a guess at part b).
If you deparse the expression fueltype:="PETROL", you'll see the changed code:
> deparse(quote(fueltype:="PETROL"))
[1] "`:=`(fueltype, \"PETROL\")"

This isn't a change, it's just the way the deparser works.  The parser recognizes := as an infix operator, but R itself never uses it, so the deparser doesn't deparse it as one.
Why does this happen with a package but not in a function?  We see
> function() { fueltype:="PETROL" }
function() { fueltype:="PETROL" }

because by default, R keeps the source code as part of a function entered at the console or via a script.  However, the default for packages is not to keep the source code.
You can override the default for packages by using the option --with-keep.source if installing the package from the command line.  Then when you print a function from the package you'll see comments and original formatting, and you won't see the := expressions rearranged.
As to part b):  are you sure that y1 is really a data.table object?  If you try to do that with a dataframe or a matrix, you'll get the error you saw.  For example,
> library(data.table)
> mtcars[, disp := 4]
Error: Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, :=, `:=`(...) and let(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").


OK thanks - good to have that first part explained....
On part b, it should definitely be a data table - immediately before it I have   data.table::setDT(y1) just to make sure and the code runs as a function and as straight code

And is.data.table(y1) returns TRUE?
